# what does dollar sign mean in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, macos

```
 CAGradientLayer *grad = [CAGradientLayer layer];
 grad.colors = $array(ColRGBA2(1, 0, 0, 1), ColRGBA2(0, 1, 0, 1), ColRGBA2(0, 0, 1, 1), ColRGBA2(0, 0, 0, 0));
 grad.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
 grad.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0);


 grad.colors = $array(ColRGBA2(1, 0, 0, 1), ColRGBA2(0, 1, 0, 1), ColRGBA2(0, 0, 1, 1), ColRGBA2(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

in this sentence have a dollar sign what does this mean?any links about it?

Comment: I recommend removing the C tag, this is not valid C code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That’s not a feature of the language, these are convenience intializers for collections that some people use. For example:

```
$array(foo, bar, baz)
```

expands to:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:foo, bar, baz, nil]
```

I’m not sure if it’s worth the trouble. And I don’t have a link to the library that provides these macros, maybe somebody else does?

By the way, it looks like we will have official literals for arrays, dictionaries and some other objects in Xcode 4.4. The details appear to be under NDA at the moment, but there’s some [discussion at Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3609071).

Comment: i see thank you for your answer, it's a macro in this code i find it .not special means

Comment: I've never seen this in any Objective-C program.  Clearly it was thought up by a PHP programmer.

Comment: I, too, have never seen this before now.  This is very odd.

Comment: actually it is odd if you write for the appstore :)

Answer (score 3):

It's from the ConciseKit library

https://github.com/petejkim/ConciseKit